# Defining New Window Target When Linked from an Iframe

Tags: php, html, css

I was asked to create several websites that essentially mirror a specific live website. With the difference between the live site and the new sites being that there is a floating header that displays at the top of the page no matter how far you scroll down. This is the same technique that sites like StumbleUpon use. My initial thought was to use an Iframe, for the view portal and a absolute div for the header. However I was then asked to make it so that when someone clicks on a link within the iframe that they be taken to the actual site, in a new window. This is the part that has me thrown. Is there a way to tell the I frame to open all links in a new target? If not what would you recommend?

See attached image for clarification:
[image]

Comment: You can't run javascript on an included iframe from a different domain, so I don't think that approach will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Targeting blank in the anchor should work just fine here.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With some cross browser hacks you may be able to tell when the iframe src changes, on that basis you could then reload the page in a new window. It isn't possible though to tell what the new URL is, so it won't be the best user experience as you'll be sending them back to the page that you loaded originally.
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/